# Exit not working inside loop and if condition

Tags: loops, unix

I have a list file containing:

```
PATH1=/opt/apps/skum_edw/Source_Bad/
PATH2=/opt/apps/skum_edw/Source_Backup/
PATH3=/hfd  
PATH4=/opt/apps/skum_edw/Target_Backup/
```

Also I have a script to check whether dir is present or not:

```
cat Path.lis | cut -d'=' -f2 | while read path
do
    [ -d $path ]
then
    echo $path is present
else
    echo $path is not present
exit 1
fi
done
echo That is the end of script
```

The problem is that the `exit 1` is not working. And I am getting last line also as output. How to do it? And what is the reason of this?

Comment: Please format your question correctly: use code formatting. Also, there's at least an `if` missing: copy-paste your script properly.

Comment: I have never seen so ugly formatted code here!

Answer (score 1):

There's no `IF`, while there is an `FI`.